# Android: problems reading shared image by other apps

Tags: android, image, share, inputstream, android-contentresolver

I am developing an app that uses images shared from other apps (e.g. gallery, browser).

The code:

```
    public void handleImage() {        
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri imgUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

    if (imgUri != null){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            InputStream imgInputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri);
            Bitmap img = (BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgInputStream));
            img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            byte[] imgByteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putByteArray("IMAGE_BYTEARRAY", imgByteArray);

            FragmentEntityEdit fragmentEntityEdit = new FragmentEntityEdit();
            fragmentEntityEdit.setArguments(bundle);
            changeFragment(fragmentEntityEdit,true,true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I share image from browser for the first time, it works fine. Fragment is started and image can be loaded to ImageView.
But for the second time I use share option of the browser, it is not loading the new image. (Only if I clear application data manually.)

UPDATE (ImageView image load in fragmentEntityEdit):
in OnCreateView:

```
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        imgByteArray = bundle.getByteArray("IMAGE_BYTEARRAY");
    }

    ImageView imgOfEntity = view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_imgofentity);

    if (imgByteArray != null) {
        imgOfEntity.setImageBitmap(null);

        Glide
                .with(getActivity())
                .load(imgByteArray)
                .into(imgOfEntity);
    }
```

Do you know how can I reach newer images?

Comment: Have you debug your code to check if there is any error? Also, post the code where you set the image in the image view.

Comment: I have updated, before I wrote here I was debugging but nothing unusual happened. Thanks for commenting

Comment: how do you finishing this fragment "FragmentEntityEdit"?? Is this a "DialogFragment"??

Comment: No, this is public class FragmentEntityEdit extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to share bitmap data via Bundle. The (documentation)[https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles] states "When sending data via an intent, you should be careful to limit the data size to a few KB. Sending too much data can cause the system to throw a TransactionTooLargeException exception". 
Why don't you pass the Uri to the Fragment and read the InputStream there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have posted, the issue is related to your `Glide` call.
`Glide` is not loading the new request into your `ImageView`, due to its cache.

In order to fix it, you can try something like this:

```
Glide.with(imgOfEntity.getContext())
    .load(imgByteArray)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .into(imgOfEntity);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was really simple... (Not for me this time :))